# Is T-SQL CROSS APPLY more efficient for calculations than adding the expression or calculations in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I want to do some calculations which way is more efficient

1. First way Calculations and expressions in the SELECT

```
SELECT ID,
        CASE WHEN COLUMN1 ='A' THEN 'YES' END AS COLUMN1,
        CAST('20201012' AS DATE) AS DATE
FROM TABLE
```

2. Second way, expressions and calculations in CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT ID,
        CAL.COLUMN1,
        CAL.DATECOL
FROM TABLE
CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT  CASE WHEN COLUMN1 ='A' THEN 'YES' END AS COLUMN1,
                CAST('20201012' AS DATE) AS DATECOL
) AS CAL
```

appreciate any comments, thanks

Comment: Put them both in the same query window and turn on "Include Execution Plan" and see.

Comment: **In theory** should be the same

Comment: I agree with Dale.  Its not really a question, its just something you should give a try.

Comment: yeah, i've tried and both scenarios look the same to me but i have a friend who states cross apply is better and i wanted  to have other insights, i appreciate all of your comments

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the expressions once, then I imagine they will be very similar in performance.  There might be a slight overhead for the `CROSS APPLY` providing an input source for the values, but this would be very minor.

If you refer to the expressions more than once, then I would expect the `CROSS APPLY` to be better -- the functions would only be evaluated once.  Actually, SQL Server could optimize the query to only run function calls once, but there is no guarantee.

That said, I would recommend using `VALUES` rather than `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ID, CAL.COLUMN1, CAL.DATECOL
FROM TABLE CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN COLUMN1 ='A' THEN 'YES' END AS COLUMN1,
              CAST('20201012' AS DATE)
             )
     ) V(COLUMN1, DATECOL)
```

Comment: Why do you suggest using values instead of select?

Comment: @DaleK . . . It is more concise.

Comment: For a single row it is not more concise. `SELECT col` vs the equivalent `VALUES` clause is much the same length. The conciseness comes into play with multiple rows as no need to specify `UNION ALL`